# Получение закрытой документации

Tags: документация

Какие есть способы получить докуменацию на внутренние компоненты различной техники? Бывает, что остаются от сломанных приборов экраны, передатчики, контроллеры, датчики или что-то подобное, в общем всё, что выкидывать жалко. Или хочется немного модифицировать имеющийся продукт хотя бы программным образом, попатчить прошивку.

Как и у кому можно обращаться с оным вопросом? Могут ли они выслать исходники, требуемую документацию на железяки али ядро? Хотя бы и на устаревшую на несколько лет технику, которую более не производят.

Или остаётся уповать на осциллограф и дизассемблер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно - "Или остаётся уповать на осциллограф и дизассемблер?"
Реально - можно найти на многие компоненты схемы и описания. Не на все, конечно. Отдельно стоят заказные компоненты, выпущенные под конкретного заказчика и конкретное у-во. Но метод аналогии серьезно помогает.

PS: по ноутбукам и компьютерной комплектухе можно обращаться ко мне напрямую :-)

Comment: Немного добавлю: ну Geohot же как то модифицировал PS3 без документации)

Comment: Ну, вообще-то схемы на PS3 при желании (огромном) найти можно

Comment: Ну, в данный момент меня интересует телефон Sony Ericsson K700 =) Хочу ему полезностей добавить =D

Спасибо разработчикам - комментариев и отладочных сообщений в прошивке выше крыши ^^

Comment: Посмотреть схему на Sony Ericsson K700 - не проблема. Можно попытаться поизучать вопрос - а не было ли на то же шасси более продвинутой модели. Но вряд ли. А название процессора и микросхем вряд ли даст информацию :-(
Как можно напрямую связаться? Что-то в профиле не вижу опции "отправить письмо участнику"

Comment: Схема есть частичная =) Контроллер там TI D751668A (ARM9E-J) - спецзаказ ерикссона у Texas Instruments. Ясно, что закрытый. Даташита, ессно, нема. Так что ковыряюсь в асме - изучаю, значится =D Надо пропатчить немного и включить интерактивную отладку да добавить прошивку "на лету". Будет легче:3

А адрес почты разве не виден в профиле? =)

Comment: Сайт - да, адрес почты - нет. Глюк?

Comment: Видимо, так задумано .з.

yateplofizik[ня]yandex.ru